# what does device called /dev/fbsnap0 works for in linux?

Tags: linux

As title

I google it but find nothing mentions it detaily.

I saw lots device in /dev/ such as /dev/fbsnap0, /dev/fbsnap1...etc

Does anyone can explain?

Comment: Related: [find driver module associated with device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97676/how-to-find-the-driver-module-associated-with-a-device-on-linux). If you know the module, googling for it should give more results. Guess: fb = framebuffer, snap = snapshots?

Comment: Welcome to superuser please refer this link to learn that, https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask how to ask question.